# Why same scene has diferent size when i export it to three.js and babylon.js

Tags: three.js

When i try export scene from blender to three.js , json file has large size, but the same scene export to babylon.js has size less. Why so?

Comment: Please provide more details in your question, for example the addon your are using.

Comment: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender
https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/tree/master/Exporters/Blender

Comment: The same scene.
When exporting for three.js file size - 40mb.
When exporting for babylon.js file size - 6mb.

Comment: Just with a quick search on google you find that three.js and babylon.js construction is pretty different, you can't really compare them

Answer (score 1):

There are many reasons this could happen:

- three.js and babylon.js formats are just different, and may encode things in different ways
- the three.js exporter may be including extra data that isn't in the babylonjs file like normals or tangents (whether that's data you want or not, who knows)

tl;dr this is fine and normal. Whichever engine you decide to use, both support many formats (FBX, glTF, OBJ) and some may be more efficient than either JSON format. [glTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-Exporter/) and [Draco](http://github.com/google/draco) are may give smaller sizes, in particular.